# Monotouch Binding and FacebookSDK

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

MonoTouch Binding refers to my Static Library, which uses FacebookSDK.

Сhain projects:

```
MonoTouch App -> MonoTouch Binding -> My Static Library -> FacebookSDK
```

When you add interfaces ApiDefinition, arise errors associated with FacebookSDK how to solve this problem? Maybe someone has already encountered this problem?

```
Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: 
_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBFriendPickerViewController. If '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBFriendPickerViewController' is a
 protocol from a third-party binding, please check that it has the [Protocol] attribute in its 
api definition file, otherwise verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and
 native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5211)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove reference of current the Facebook SDK framework and add the Facebook SDK again by drag and drop it in framework folder. 
This will add Facebook SDK path automatically.